# Shopping cart function in python

Tags: python

I am currently on a task in python and i need help with this and i am to

Create a class called ShoppingCart.

Create a constructor that has no arguments and sets the total attribute to zero, and initializes an empty dict attribute named items.

Create a method add_item that requires item_name, quantity and price arguments. This method should add the cost of the added items to the current value of total. It should also add an entry to the items dict such that the key is the item_name and the value is the quantity of the item.

Create a method remove_item that requires similar arguments as add_item. It should remove items that have been added to the shopping cart and are not required. This method should deduct the cost of these items from the current total and also update the items dict accordingly. If the quantity of items to be removed exceeds current quantity in cart, assume that all entries of that item are to be removed.

Create a method checkout that takes in cash_paid and returns the value of balance from the payment. If cash_paid is not enough to cover the total, return Cash paid not enough.

Create a class called Shop that has a constructor which initializes an attribute called quantity at 100.

Make sure Shop inherits from ShoppingCart.

In the Shop class, override the remove_item method, such that calling Shop's remove_item with no arguments decrements quantity by one.

Below is the sample test code for this

```
import unittest;

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.cart = ShoppingCart()
    self.shop = Shop()

def test_cart_property_initialization(self):
    self.assertEqual(self.cart.total, 0, msg='Initial value of total not correct')
    self.assertIsInstance(self.cart.items, dict, msg='Items is not a dictionary')

def test_add_item(self):
    self.cart.add_item('Mango', 3, 10)
    self.assertEqual(self.cart.total, 30, msg='Cart total not correct after adding items')
    self.assertEqual(self.cart.items['Mango'], 3, msg='Quantity of items not correct after adding item')

def test_add_item_hidden(self):
    self.cart.add_item('Mango', 3, 10)
    self.cart.add_item('Orange', 16, 10)
    self.assertEqual(self.cart.total, 190, msg='Cart total not correct after adding items')
    self.assertEqual(self.cart.items['Orange'], 16, msg='Quantity of items not correct after adding item')

def test_remove_item(self):
    self.cart.add_item('Mango', 3, 10)
    self.cart.remove_item('Mango', 2, 10)
    self.assertEqual(self.cart.total, 10, msg='Cart total not correct after removing item')
    self.assertEqual(self.cart.items['Mango'], 1, msg='Quantity of items not correct after removing item')

def test_remove_item_hidden(self):
    self.cart.add_item('Mango', 3, 10)
    self.cart.add_item('Orange', 16, 10)
    self.cart.remove_item('Mango', 2, 10)
    self.assertEqual(self.cart.total, 170, msg='Cart total not correct after removing item')
    self.assertEqual(self.cart.items['Mango'], 1, msg='Quantity of items not correct after removing item')
    self.cart.remove_item('Mango', 2, 10)
    self.assertEqual(self.cart.total, 160, msg='Cart total not correct after removing item')
    with self.assertRaises(KeyError):
        self.cart.items['Mango']

def test_checkout_returns_correct_value(self):
    self.cart.add_item('Mango', 3, 10)
    self.cart.add_item('Orange', 16, 10)
    self.assertEqual(self.cart.checkout(265), 75, msg='Balance of checkout not correct')
    self.assertEqual(self.cart.checkout(25), 'Cash paid not enough', msg='Balance of checkout not correct')


def test_shop_is_instance_of_shopping_cart(self):
    self.assertTrue(isinstance(self.shop, ShoppingCart), msg='Shop is not a subclass of ShoppingCart')

def test_shop_initializaton(self):
    self.assertEqual(self.shop.quantity, 100, msg='Shop quantity not initialized correctly')

def test_shop_remove_item_method(self):
    for i in range(15):
        self.shop.remove_item()

    self.assertEqual(self.shop.quantity, 85)
```

I have tried to solve this with the code below

```
class ShoppingCart(object):

  def __init__(self):
      self.total = 0 
      self.items = {}

  def add_item(self,item_name,quantity,price):
      self.items[item_name] = quantity
      self.total += price*quantity

  def remove_item(self,item_name,quantity,price):
      if quantity < self.items[item_name] and quantity >= 0:
          self.total -= price*quantity
          self.items[item_name] -= quantity
      elif quantity >= self.items[item_name] :
          del self.items[item_name]

  def checkout(self,cash_paid):
      if cash_paid >= self.total:
          return cash_paid - self.total
      else:
          return "Cash paid not enough"

class Shop(ShoppingCart):
  def __init__(self):
      self.quantity = 100

  def remove_item(self):
      self.quantity -= 1
```

All other task are solved but The error i get back in return when i run the test is

```
 test_remove_item_hidden
 170 != 160 : Cart total not correct after removing item
```

I can't seem to locate the problem. Please any help would do considering i am new to python. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This statement `quantity < self.items[item_name]` doesn't seem right. Rather looks like it's intended be a check that `self.items[item_name]` exist.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek i don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

While deleting, else case calls `del` which only deletes the item, but doesn't update the cart total. You should use that quantity to reduce the price from the total first:

```
...
else:
    self.total -= price*self.items[item_name]
    del self.items[item_name]
...
```

Comment: Are you sure you have added this to right place? I have executed your code now and all tests pass when above line is added.